# How can I get Perl to accept negative numbers as command-line arguments?

Tags: perl, command-line

Is there a way to get Perl to avoid treating negative values as command-line switches? Neither stringifying nor backslashing the argument seems to help under Linux:

```
$ perl  -e 'print "@ARGV\n";' 4 5
  4 5

$ perl  -e 'print "@ARGV\n";' -4 5
  Unrecognized switch: -4  (-h will show valid options).

$ perl -e 'print "@ARGV\n";' "-4" 5
  Unrecognized switch: -4  (-h will show valid options).

$ perl -e 'print "@ARGV\n";' '-4' 5
  Unrecognized switch: -4  (-h will show valid options).

$ perl -e 'print "@ARGV\n";' \-4 5
  Unrecognized switch: -4  (-h will show valid options).
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ perl -E "say join ', ', @ARGV" -- -1 2 3
-1, 2, 3
```

The trick is using the double-hyphen (`--`) to end the option parsing. [Double-hyphen is a GNU convention](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces):

```
$ touch -a
usage: touch [-acfm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] file ...
$ touch -- -a
$ ls
-a
```

Comment: Ha, thanks for the link, daxim. I thought the double dash had something to do with GNU, but failed to Google it.

Comment: The '--' is a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) standard; see Guideline 10 in §12.2 of the URL.